# How to extract data from GCP Big Query table using Apache Nifi?

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-nifi

I need to load the data from big query table using nifi.

I used executesql nifi processor to load data from big query table.

when i was executing processor, i got following error.

**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.google.api.gax.rpc.RequestUrlParamsEncoder.(com.google.api.gax.rpc.RequestParamsExtractor)'**

configure DBCPConnectionPooling Service in following class name - com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc42.Driver

I am using nifi1.21.0 version.
download latest version of big query jdbc driver(version 4.2) and put into nifi/lib folder

I also used correct connection url when configuring pooling service.

How to solve this error?